# a way to make python selenium's html to be loaded after everything dynamic is loaded?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, iframe

I'm trying to make a script that automates article editing via python selenium, but here's the problem:

after opening the page the page itself comes out well, but I couldn't get the element I wanted.

turns out the element is inside some , which selenium didn't open/read.

when I use

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_id('cafe_main').get_attribute('src')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

it didn't work. got "NoSuchFrameException: Message: no such frame" error.

- and when I typed the src manually the exact same page would get loaded. there's a JS preventing only that part of the iframe to be loaded.

after that I tried this:

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//*[@id='modifyFormBtn']/p/a"))
    )
finally:
    print(driver.page_source)
```

but still nope.... just get a timeoutException and print() at finally part showed iframe didnt got loaded.

so... is there some other way to make this thing to be loaded?

EDIT:
I tried deleting get_attribute('src') at the driver.switch_to.frame(iframe), I got this error.

> Message: unknown error: Element  is not
>   clickable at point (784, 864). Other element would receive the click:
>   ...   (Session info:
>   chrome=58.0.3029.110)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700
>   (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.14393 x86_64)

http://cafe.naver.com/twcenter/22498 this is the link I'm working with, there supposed to be articles in div tag, id="main-area" area, but only shows  in the selenium

EDIT2:

my full code:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

chromePath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'chromedriver')
# setting up browser. this is Chrome-based.
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromePath)

# tha address. for testing it out
driver.get('http://cafe.naver.com/twcenter/22498')

driver.implicitly_wait(15)  # tried waiting if dynamic script gets loaded. it didn't.

# opening the frame. 
iframe = driver.find_element_by_id('cafe_main')  
print(iframe)
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

# an xpath going to a button opening forum post lists. 
xpath = ".//*[@id='main-area']/div[3]/div/div[2]/p/a"


try:
    # not working at the moment as iframe is not being dynamically updated in selenium. 
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: `iframe = driver.find_element_by_id('main')`
this is correct, remove the get_attribute and try, it will work. And can you provide a link to the website?

Comment: Simply try `driver.switch_to.frame("main")`

Comment: http://cafe.naver.com/twcenter/22498 this is the page, dunno if guests can see this article. oh and minor thing -  the id was "cafe_main" instead of "main", which still doesn't work.

Comment: @MrSolid51 Thanks for updating the link as http://cafe.naver.com/twcenter/22498 Can you please consider updating us your exact manual steps, your code block & the error which you are facing in the Question area? Thanks

Comment: @MrSolid51, share more code. Switching to `iframe` cannot trigger `Element is not clickable at point()` exception. It seem that you're already in `iframe` and you make click on element which currently overlapped

Comment: hmm that's weird.... well I posted my full code now I'm confused, and that exception don't come out anymore :S just `Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='modifyFormBtn']/p/a"}`